# React - test image and conditional render element from Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code I would like to check if image exist on server and then display image if true otherwise display span element. I wrote following code but it didn't return any value.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class ImageResolver extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        const checkImg = (src) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let img = new Image()
                img.onload = () => resolve(true);
                img.onerror = () => reject(false);
                img.src = src
            })
        }

        const getImageOrText = () => {

            checkImg(this.props.src)
                .then((result) => {
                    return <img src={this.props.src} alt="test"/>
                }).catch((e) => {
                    return <span>Add image to your Profile</span>
                })
        }

        return (

            <div>
                {getImageOrText()}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: you have to use state for this. you cannot render asynchronously

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show me how? Thx.

Comment: Read the documentation, there are plenty of examples https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: You get me wrong. I know what is a state but I don't see a way how to fix my problem using state.

Comment: store the result of your promise (whether it errored or not) in state, then once the promise resolves, check that state to determine whether to render the image or not

Comment: I can write an answer in a bit